# how do i update/insert values into a row with multiple columns through a form

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

suppose a sql server table with 12 columns needs to be filled row by row using html form table. I have created textboxes using for loop and then I have to insert values from that form into sql table. I am not able to do it. this is the code I have used

```
echo '< form name="myForm" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" align="center" class="form-inline">';
    echo'< table border="1" >';
    echo ' < tr>< td>< /td>';
    for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        echo '< td>< input type="text" placeholder="enter text" name="mytext[]" value="0">< /td>';
    }
    echo'< /tr>';
echo '< /table>
< input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
< /form>';
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    foreach($_POST['mytext'] as $value)
    {
        echo $value." ";    
    }
    $result=mssql_query("insert into test_table (p1,p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12) values ('".$value."')");
    }
```

the table has one id column, and 12 different columns. it gives me the error:

There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

notice that all textboxes are not filled in so some columns should get 0

Comment: this is an array. how do I insert the values as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    echo '< form name="myForm" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" align="center" class="form-inline">';
        echo'< table border="1" >';
        echo ' < tr>< td>< /td>';
        for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            echo '< td>< input type="text" placeholder="enter text" name="mytext[]" value="0">< /td>';
        }
        echo'< /tr>';
    echo '< /table>
    < input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    < /form>';

$valueArr = array();
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        foreach($_POST['mytext'] as $value)
        {
            $valueArr [] = "'".$value."'";    
        }
        $result=mssql_query("insert into test_table (p1,p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12) values (".implode(",",$valueArr).")
");
        }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark my answer as a "correct answer"